# Splunk field extraction Regex

Tags: regex, splunk

I want to extract a field in splunk however Splunk Regex won't work so I am writing my own Regex. However I am struggling to extract. Can someone please help?

My String:

```
Node ID=nbgcXYZdfdscxm2
Node ID=NBGDFDFCCXM2
Node ID=BURECXM2
```

Expected Output:

```
cXYZdfds
DFDFC
BURE
```

So far I was able to write this 
`.*(?i)Node ID=[^nbg](?P<CM_Node_Id>[^\]cxm\d]+)`

Comment: [`^Node ID=(?:nbg)?(.*?)(?:cxm\d)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/w1BgqC/1)?

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/w1BgqC/1)

```
^Node ID=(?:nbg)?(.*?)(?:cxm\d)?$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Node ID=nbgcXYZdfdscxm2
Node ID=NBGDFDFCCXM2
Node ID=BURECXM2
```

#### Output

```
cXYZdfds
DFDFC
BURE
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `Node ID=` Match this sequence of characters literally
- `(?:nbg)?` Optional match of `nbg` literally
- `(.*?)` Capture any character any number of times, but as few as possible into capture group 1
- `(?:cxm\d)?` Optional match of `cxm` literally, followed by a digit
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Answers provided above should work fine. Try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cBYjch/1/) for Splunk

```
.*Node ID=(?:nbg)?(.*?)(?P<CM_Node_Id>.+)cxm2
```